# How would I create a table control similar to the one shown?

Tags: c#, datagrid

I've got a table from an existing LabView VI (ewww!) that I need to replicate in C#.  The table is shown in the image below.  Each field will be populated with data returned by status queries to an external device, likely from within a dedicated status thread (when I implement it...).  Is there any control, or direction I should take when extending an existing control for the table-like display of my query results?  DataGridView seems like overkill for this, but the table layout container populated with TextBox controls seems inelegant.  I'd like some insight, if anyone can offer it.  Also, please feel free to shut me down if this has been asked already (though my search turned up nothing I could relate to...).  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView is the only suitable control here.  Anything else either doesn't have enough grid editing capabilities (like ListView) or is fugly-slow like individual controls in a TLP.